# Trouble with CG fast track course- Geometry issue with sword Guard

Tags: geometry

I am trying to figure out what is wrong with my sword guard. been playing around with different things but to no avail. I do not mind doing this over again but I would like to know what is wrong. File -> https://pasteall.org/blend/7edd68e550ef494694d9ac79fc9907f8
Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Select the guard and go into Edit mode. Select All and then go to Mesh > Clean Up > Delete Loose. While everything is still selected, SHIFT>N to recalculate the normals and you should be good to go. - There was an edge inside the mesh which wasn't connected to any faces that seemed to be causing the shading problem and the normals were facing the wrong way on a small part of the mesh.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome.